# Login-logoff problem, deactivate account

Tags: support

I have been register onto this site and onto Stack Overflow.

But another user cannot log in into this site because it is always re-directing me within my account. How can I de-activate my account?

Comment: did your clear your cache after logout ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to de-activate your account. Just try this.

- There is a logout button, click on it.

[image]

- Clear your Browser's history

Now another user can easily be able to login in the same computer. And if you want to de-activate your account, just following this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion